# PHP Clear buffer during for loop

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Streaming Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><a href="#" id="test">Test Ajax Streaming</a></center>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "test1.php", true);
        xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
            console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);
        }
        //xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        //        console.log("Complete = " + xhr.responseText);
        //    }
        //}
        xhr.send();
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test1.php**

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++):
    sleep(1);
    echo "$i\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
endfor;
```

after click on link in **test.html** page, console show this results :

- 1
- 1
  2
- 1
  2
  3

What is the method to clean buffer before echo `$i` to get result like this :

- 1
- 2
- 3

Thank you

Comment: `flush()` doesn't work properly with AJAX.

Comment: I think you have to read the documentation about [`onprogress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress) event.

Comment: Did you eventually solve this issue ? As I am encountering the same now and ob_clean, neither ob_flush do help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ob_clean();` It will clear the whole output buffer:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++):
    sleep(1);
    ob_clean();
    echo "$i\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();

endfor;
```

Comment: I've never used flush and ajax so I don't have any practical experience of it. But ob_clean() is the function you asked to clear the buffer